# Как считать сложность алгоритма?

Tags: алгоритм, сложность

Что я имею ввиду когда говорю о подсчете сложности алгоритма? К примеру вы написали какую-то функцию, которая: сортирует два массива, проходится по ним циклом составляя на их основе некий новый массив и в конце, прежде чем вернуть полученный массив, реверсирует его - какая в итоге будет сложность алгоритма? Я знаю что операция сортировки имеет логарифмическую сложность, а цикл по элементам и реверс - линейную. Но какова сложность самой функции в результате? Она будет равна самой медленной операции (в таком случае это будет линейная сложность) или это будет какой-то новый вариант, где мы просто сложим все 4 имеющихся сложности (вроде 2 log_comp + 2 linear_comp)?

Comment: если мы говорим о O(n), то сложность будет соотвествовать самой седленной части вашего описания, то есть сложность будет линейно-логарифмическая или nLog(n)

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Сложность, которая считается от О большое часто расходится с тем, что будет лучше на практике, потому что этот метод априори работает с бесконечностью.

Comment: Сдается мне, что в вашем случае это O(n log n + m log m) - две сортировки.

Answer (score 5):

Сложность алгоритма расчистывается показывая относительный класс. Например если сравнивать O(n^2) и O(n), то деление их друг на друга приведёт к бесконечному увеличению :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и это значит, что эти скорости отличаются на порядок.

А если добавить к логарифмической сложности одну линейную, то принципиально отношение отличаться не будет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если это добавление не слишком громоздкое. Например при маленьких значениях `n` может быть увеличено время на треть, а при больших уже только +10%. Сложность будет O(n*Log[n]).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если например добавить `n^(3/2)` то узнать что из них перевесит можно опять делением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бесконечность означает, что при увеличении количества `n` степень `n^(3/2)` будет намного больше чем логарифм `n*Log[n]`. Сложность будет O(n^(3/2)).

---

*Если отношение в скорости отличаются на конечное число, например в два раза, то это константное соотношение на класс скорости не влияет.*